# How to restore file from iCloud Backup

Tags: iphone, ios, icloud, backup, restore

I lost an important sqlite file during the upgrade to iOS 9 beta. Luckily the file is backed up on iCloud.

When restoring from the iCloud backup, iOS downloads the data file along with the app, but then deletes the app and file immediately during the process (most likely due to the app is not a finished app available on the App Store; it is under development).

So my question is, is there a way to restore that beta app's data file?

Or, is there a way to prevent the restore process from deleting apps that it thinks should not exist?

Answer (score 1):

Apple has provided detailed steps about how to restore files from iCloud on this page, you should have a look. https://support.apple.com/kb/ph12521?locale=en_US

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to access individual iCloud files if you have a Mac.  I've done this (admittedly not recently though).

There are instructions here: 
http://www.macworld.com/article/2310807/how-to-access-icloud-files-from-your-mac.html